# Forge Viewer show UI while adding Markups

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm working with the MarkupsCore extension and want to keep my added UI open inside the viewer while adding or working with Markups.

From what I can tell once I call enterEditMode the UI won't return until I hide all of my Markups. The buttons I have added don't seem to change state and their still marked as visible when I'm debugging, yet they don't show.

I tried setVisibility on the objects but the method returns false because it evaluates the buttons as not hidden.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question right, that's expected as you cannot move/rotate/zoom the model when editing the Markups, mainly because these are SVG shapes on top of the view. Ideally you should also keep the Viewer state to restore when viewing the markups later.

Comment: Right I understand not wanting to move or rotate, but I want to have UI for other purposes. In this case I want a panel that shows what markup tool they currently have selected, and a button to stop editing markups. That way I know the user is done and I can save them out.